# Heat and Glow Fireplace

Tags: fireplace

I built my house in 1995 with a Heat & Glow fireplace that is controlled with a wall switch. I flipped the switch off and it did not cut the fireplace off. I replaced it and it worked for a day. Now I can't cut it off again from the switch. I threw the original switch away. Is there more of an issue than the switch? What should i do?

Comment: Can you please edit in the model number? This sounds like a gas control valve issue but the model number can help others give input.

Comment: You can learn a lot about how your unit works by getting the model number and downloading the owners manual from **https://www.heatnglo.com/**. The model number is on a label inside the control compartment (open doors, remove compartment access panel). You can also manually turn the unit off and on from there.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we could help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.